# How to refactor the below ruby code?

Tags: ruby, oop

This code consists of an `if`/`else` ladder. It checks the `@tokens[0]` value and calls the function on the basis of its content:

```
if @tokens[0] == "add"
  @calculator.add(@tokens[1].to_f)
elsif @tokens[0] == "subtract"
  @calculator.subtract(@tokens[1].to_f)
elsif @tokens[0] == "multiply"
  @calculator.multiply(@tokens[1].to_f)
elsif @tokens[0] == "divide"
  @calculator.divide(@tokens[1].to_f)
elsif @tokens[0] == "sqr"
  @calculator.sqr
elsif @tokens[0] == "sqrt"
  @calculator.sqrt
elsif @tokens[0] == "cube"
  @calculator.cube
elsif @tokens[0] == "cubert"
  @calculator.cubert
end
```

I am using a hashmap to refactor the code. Is there any other way to refactor it other than hashmap?

Comment: There are tons of ways code can be refactored. What have you tried? What is the problem you're trying to solve / goal you are trying to achieve by refactoring? Less code? Improved performance? Better organization? More obfuscation? How did your attempts fall short of those goals?

Comment: @Chris I am interested to your _super powers_ ;)

Comment: You say you're using a hash map, however your code shows nothing that demonstrates it. `@tokens[0]` is not a hash accessor, unless you're using `0` as a key. Instead it looks like you're using an array. Please supply sample input. As is, there is a lot that can be DRY'd.

Comment: @theTinMan : the above code  shows the basic if/else ladder and I know how to refactor using hashmap. I want you know any other way to refactor it

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt to read thoughts:

```
@calculator.public_send \
  case @tokens[0]
  when 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'
    @tokens[0], @tokens[1].to_f
  when 'sqr', 'sqrt', 'cube', 'cubert'
    @tokens[0]
  else fail 'Unsupported operation'
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this untested code?

```
action = @tokens[0].to_sym
case action
when :add, :subtract, :multiply, :divide
  @calculator.send(action, @tokens[1].to_f)
else
  @calculator.send(action)
end
```

Comment: What was an improvement compared to my answer?

Comment: Readability is important. It's also simpler. While yours is similar in that you're using a `send`, the convolutions to gather the parameters are visual noise.

Comment: And yours accepts any garbage as token, what obviously contradicts OP´s intentions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
have_param = ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"]

known_tokens = ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide", "sqr", "sqrt", "cube", "cubert"]

t_0_value = @tokens[0]
if known_tokens.include?(t_0_value)
  ( have_param.include?(t_0_value) ? @calculator.send(t_0_value, @tokens[1].to_f) : @calculator.send(t_0_value) )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@calculator.send(@tokens[0],
  *case @tokens[0]
  when "add".freeze, "subtract".freeze, "multiply".freeze, "divide".freeze
    @tokens[1].to_f
  when "sqr".freeze, "sqrt".freeze, "cube".freeze, "cubert".freeze
    nil
  end
)
```

Comment: can you make it with the help of runtime polymorphism, like pull out the add as a class.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of way to refactor this, here is to easy ones:

You can use a case statement that will look a bit more clean, like this:

```
case @tokens[0]
when "add" 
  @calculator.add(@tokens[1].to_f)
when "subtract"
  @calculator.subtract(@tokens[1].to_f)
when "multiply"
  @calculator.multiply(@tokens[1].to_f)
when "divide"
  @calculator.divide(@tokens[1].to_f)
when "sqr"
  @calculator.sqr
when "sqrt"
  @calculator.sqrt
when "cube"
  @calculator.cube
when "cubert"
  @calculator.cubert
end
```

You can put the conditions in its own hash:

```
cases = { "add" => @calculator.add(@tokens[1].to_f),
"subtract" => @calculator.subtract(@tokens[1].to_f),
"multiply" => @calculator.multiply(@tokens[1].to_f),
"divide" => @calculator.divide(@tokens[1].to_f),
"sqr" => @calculator.sqr,
"sqrt" => @calculator.sqrt,
"cube" => @calculator.cube,
"cubert" => @calculator.cubert }

cases[@tokens[0]]
```

You can use eval to call the function, and you will not need to make a case for every operation:

```
case @tokens[0]
when 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'
  eval("@calculator.#{@tokens[0]}(#{@tokens[1].to_f})")
when 'sqr', 'sqrt', 'cube', 'cubert'
  eval("@calculator.#{@tokens[0]}")
end
```

this will call the function and use .to_f on tokens[0] if its in the array

```
@calculator.send(tokens[0], ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'].include? tokens[0] ? tokens[1].to_f : tokens[1])
```

You can put this in the @calculator class and always call @calculator.calculate(tokens)

```
def calculate(tokens)
    send(tokens[0], ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'].include? tokens[0] ? tokens[1].to_f : tokens[1])
end
```

Comment: Had a good laugh at the `eval` "solution". **Don't do that**!

Comment: Second solution (with hash) apparently evaluates everything, making e.g. subtraction of zero impossible due to exception thrown in `divide`.

Comment: @lassvi : can you make it with the help of runtime polymorphism, like pull out the add as a class.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, if you want it to be all done by the one class you can add it as a own function in the class, i added some code to my answer that shows some examples.